# Stuck with CakePHP project

Tags: codeigniter, cakephp

I'm currently sitting on a project which is built in CakePHP by a developer I've never met and which isn't working on the project any longer. Our company wants a lot of nice new features on the project, and I don't feel too eager to create these features since I find CakePHP more unlogical to work with than Codeigniter, and I would prefer to do all my projects in CodeIgniter. The though has struck my mind to basicly rebuild our project in CodeIgniter, but that would of course mean an investment of time.

So basicly what would be the best approach? The project is rather but not too big. I could try to upgrade CakePHP 1.3 to 2.0 and see if it's more logical and try to feel good in CakePHP. It just feels like CodeIgniter syncs better with my brain. I'm a sole developer on this project and no one else who cares what framework I'm using.

Feel free to refer to own project decisions and results. If you feel that this question belongs at the programmers site, please move it.

Comment: What will happen if, after a migration to CodeIgniter, at your turn you will leave the project, and some other developer is required to take over? :-) Seriously, what is the platform-of-choice within your company? What does your company have experience or vesting in?

Comment: Because this is an question which is more likely to have subjective answers, programmers.stackexchange.com would be a more logical place.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to go for a rewrite I recommend using [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com) instead. After a few projects with CodeIgniter I switched to Yii because it makes you much more productive. The reason why you should switch is that you'll probably find it easier to translate stuff from Cake to Yii and a lot of crud stuff can be autogenerated by gii tool.

Comment: Would you say Yii goes by the same logic as CakePHP? Personally, I really dislike automized actions such as encrypting $_POST['password'] by default. Also prefer to chose to render page instead of loading auto. I want my script to do what I tell it to do, not what I thinks I want it to do.

Comment: Yii is a middle ground between CodeIgniter and CakePHP. It gives you all benefits of code generation, real AR pattern (with Foreign key support) from Cake, with flexibility to do anything your way from CodeIgniter. I dislike how Cake forces you to name database objects, files, etc. Yii is much more flexible there, although it does provide reasonable defaults which are good for teams of more developers (no need to invent your own conventions). It takes a little bit more time to learn it compared to CI, but still less than Cake. If you plan to do more PHP projects in future, it's worth learning.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 2 is much better, faster and more logical than 1.3. If you will decide to migrate you can do that by using console `cake upgrade all`. I used it for one very little project (one of cake's plugins) and it is really very nice feature. This would do the greatest part of migration work for you. The full migration guide is [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html). But as you have not written that project I would not recommend that and I would not start the migration if it is not the customer's requirement. It would be faster for you to learn 1.3 and implement new features than to migrate to Cake 2 or Codeigniter. CakePHP is great when you use console.

It is better to know 2 frameworks than 1. Take a look at [this](http://pixelfactory.com.au/development/cakephp-vs-codeigniter-the-big-decision/) interesting article.

Answer (score 1):

I would do what you can to see if you can't keep it as a CakePHP project. While I don't prefer Cake, converting a project from one framework to another will be very time consuming (time you could have spent elsewhere, learning to work with Cake, etc).

However, if you have tried to work with Cake, don't like it, feel like you're fighting with it, etc... AND you've been given the time to convert the project to the framework of your choice (because this really isn't about Cake or CI), then I would certainly go ahead with the conversion. This would especially be the case if you will be the principle maintainer of the project for the foreseeable future.